# An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command Original error: Could not find adb.exe in

Tags: android, webdriver, appium

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.

> Original error: Could not find adb.exe in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk;\platform-tools\adb.exe,C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk;\emulator\adb.exe,C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk;\tools\adb.exe,C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk;\tools\bin\adb.exe.
>   Do you have the Android SDK installed at
>   'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk;'?

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be definitely caused by wrong folder names in the PATH variable:
Please check your PATH environment variable and make sure you have (at least) the following folder (no semi colon on it):

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across same problem.

1. Open the Control Panel.
2. Go to Advanced System Settings.
3. Click on Environment Variables.
4. Now you will see User environment for hp and System Variables.
5. Click on new and add 2 paths:

   - ANDROID_HOME
   - Path Generally this one (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
6. Close all tabs of Appium.
7. Open Appium.

If this is not working follow next process along with the above.

1. Close all tabs of Appium.
2. Open Appium.
3. Click on Edit Configuration.
4. Now give the Android home and Java Home path here.
5. Click on Save and Restart.
6. Now fill all the previous data and click on Start Session.