# How to solve this error when starting session on Appium?

Tags: java, android, appium

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: Could not find 'adb.exe' in
>   ["C:\Users\ROG\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\platform-tools\adb.exe","C:\Users\ROG\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\emulator\adb.exe","C:\Users\ROG\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\tools\adb.exe","C:\Users\ROG\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\tools\bin\adb.exe"].
>   Do you have Android Build Tools installed at
>   'C:\Users\ROG\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools'?

I already add ANDROID_HOME in Environment Variables with correct path :

> C:\Users\ROG\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Already find in Google the same problem but still can't fix my problem

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532706/an-unknown-server-side-error-occurred-while-processing-the-command-original-erro) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53079991/how-do-i-solve-appium-desktop-could-not-find-my-adb) [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254291/starting-session-in-appium)

Comment: When you type adb in your cmd, does it work?

Comment: try to add `C:\Users\ROG\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` instead